# Error while trying to run SQL Script in Java on Oracle DB

Tags: java, sql, oracle, procedure

I'm trying to run the script below in Java, but I'm getting errors for every statement.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
VAR o_result REFCURSOR;

DECLARE
num  NUMBER;

BEGIN
num:= 123456;
stored_procedure(num =>         num,  o_result => :o_result);
END;
/

print o_result;
```

I'm getting the errors below when running it:

[image: Errors]
The code executing it is:

```
private static void selectRecordsFromDbUserTable(Connection dbConnection) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    //Calendar dateByOrder;
    String script = "query.sql";
    try{    
            new ScriptRunner(dbConnection).runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(script)));

            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());  
            }

    //return dateByOrder;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you run the file in sqlplus, does it work?

Comment: It does work if I run it in sqldeveloper.

Comment: So what is `ScriptRunner`?